# What is the correct way to end a System.Threading.Tasks.Task?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task

As per the title really.

I have a long running task that polls a message queue.

Occasionally I may wish to stop the task, do some work and then start it again. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way of stooping tasks is using [cancellation tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).